# How do i put a condition for matching the above requirement

Tags: java

```
I have a table designed this way

mysql> select * from categories limit 50;
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| category_id | T1          | T2              | T3         | T4   | T5   | T6   | T7   | T8   | T9   | T10  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|           1 | Popcorn     | Regular Pack    | NULL       | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           1 | Popcorn     | Regular Pack    | NULL       | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           1 | Popcorn     | Regular Pack    | NULL       | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Popcorn     | Bucket          | NULL       | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Popcorn     | Bucket          | NULL       | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           2 | Popcorn     | Bucket          | NULL       | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

|           7 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Apple      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           7 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Apple      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           8 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Orange     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           8 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Orange     | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           9 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Lemon      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|           9 | Soft Drinks | Fountain        | Lemon      | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
```

I need to map the data of the above table .

a sample xml file , just to repersent structure

For example ,

**Under Popcorn i must have  Regular Pack , Bucket**

**And under Soft Drinks i must have  Fountain ,  and  under Fountain  i  must have different categories Apple ,Orange and Lemon**

```
 <Popcorn>
    <Popcorn items>
     < Regular Pack>
     <Bucket >
    </Popcorn items>
    </Popcorn>

    <Softdrinks>
    <Softdrinks items>
    <Fountain>
<Fountain items>
    <Apple>
    <Orange>
    < Lemon>
</Fountain items>
    </Softdrinks items>
```

Once i retrive the values , how to put a condition that matches the above requirement ??

A psecoude code will be also sufficient for me to proccedd

```
while(rs.next())
{
  String T1 = rs.getString("T1");
  String T2 = rs.getString("T2");
  String T3 = rs.getString("T3");
  String T4 = rs.getString("T4");
  String T5 = rs.getString("T5");
  String T6 = rs.getString("T6");
  String T7 = rs.getString("T7");
  String T8 = rs.getString("T8");
  String T9 = rs.getString("T9");
  String T10 = rs.getString("T10");
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*According to me*

- You need to get two different resultset for this by quering like this

  1. `select DISTINCT T2 from tabelName where T1='PopCorn';` and
  2. `select DISTINCT T2 from tabelName where T1='SoftDrink';`

You better use `PreparedStatement` for this and `ps.setString(0,"PopCorn");`

*Apply same thing for T2 and T3.*

Now you will have `RegularPack and Bucket` after first query and `Fountain` after second and than use these values as you want to.

Comment: hey really thanks for this , now i could take some break and start with your logic . Thanks once again .